# Reverse for 'category_site' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']

Tags: python, django

**Im trying to make url and content of currently displayed product category dynamic, with using one 'category.html' template, but I just keep getting this error**

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', display_records, name="display_records"),
path('about/', about_site, name="about_site"),
path('product/<int:id>', product_site, name="product_site"),
path('all_products/', all_products_site, name="all_products_site"),
path('<slug:category>', category_site, name="category_site"),]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
def product_site(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Farfocel, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'product.html', {'product': product})


def category_site(request, category):
    category_filter = (Q(category__icontains=category))
    results = Farfocel.objects.filter(category_filter)

    return render(request, 'category.html', {'products': results})
```

product.html

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="{% url 'display_records' %}" class="breadcrumbs__link">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="{% url 'all_products_site' %}" class="breadcrumbs__link">Products</a>
</li>

<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="{% url 'category_site' product.category %}" class="breadcrumbs__link">{{ product.category }}</a>
</li>

<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="" class="breadcrumbs__link breadcrumbs__link--active">{{ product }}</a>
</li>
```

category.html

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="{% url 'display_records' %}" class="breadcrumbs__link">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="{% url 'all_products_site' %}" class="breadcrumbs__link">Products</a>
</li>

<li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a href="{% url 'category_site' product.category %}" class="breadcrumbs__link breadcrumbs__link--active">{{ product.category }}</a>
</li>
```

Honestly I tried everything I could find and I still keep failing.

Comment: Show us the view code that renders `product.html`.

Comment: Okay, it's here.

Comment: The specific `Farfocel` object you're displaying must have a blank `category` field.  Therefore the link `{% url 'category_site' product.category %}` has a blank string for `product.category`, but the url definition doesn't allow for it to be blank.

Comment: I've just checked and every product has category, but now error occurs on 'category.html'

Comment: Please add all error related code

Comment: And how can i handle this blank string?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I made it

The issue was that i was trying to get

'product.category'

```
    <li class="breadcrumbs__item">
        <a href="{% url 'category_site' product.category %}" class="breadcrumbs__link breadcrumbs__link--active">{{ product.category }}</a>
    </li>
```

while returning in views.py 'products', but typo wasn't the issue

```
def category_site(request, category):
category_filter = (Q(category__icontains=category))
results = Farfocel.objects.filter(category_filter)

return render(request, 'category.html', {'products': results})
```

Thanks to John i realized that the 'products' is a QuerySet which doesnt have 'category' field so I had to return also one of objects in this QuerySet

```
def category_site(request, category):
category_filter = (Q(category__icontains=category))
results = Farfocel.objects.filter(category_filter)
product = results[0]

return render(request, 'category.html', {'products': results, 'product': product})
```

And that way it worked, so thanks John